# SUM and multiply values in one row based on text in 1st column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My goal is simple, but I can't find the solution as I'm not sure how to call it in general.
I have a table with names of teams (**column 1**) and amount of items (**column 3**) which are assigned to them.
Table is some kind of 'outcome' list:

| Team A | Date | 200 pcs | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Team B | Date | 300 pcs | 4 |
| Team A | Date | 20 pcs | 6 |

and so on.

I would like to ask what function should I use if I require advanced return as example: if <A1:A> "Team B" then in <C1:C> * <D1:D> (which is also filtered only for current team).
Function **SUMIF** (range, criteria, sum range) is something that is suitable for my request, but multiplying messed this up .

Is there anything where I can set range and criteria and just be sure I'm working only with Team A  in my  formula?

Comment: Sumifs() or sumproduct() are what I would try.

Comment: sumproduct for sure, but try adding expected output. Also, your 3 column, those with pcs values, are those text or numeric?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You may benefit from SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1*SUBSTITUTE($C$1:$C$3;" pcs";""))*--($A$1:$A$3=A11);$D$1:$D$3)
```